# Is there a free anonymous proxy app?

Tags: software-recommendation, proxy

Is there any app like the [this](http://www.chris-pc.com/proxy/)
for ubuntu?

I basically wanna check a websites indian version so i can see the Indian Price and not in dollars US price
i'm currently in USA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just searching for http proxy you can try `privoxy` or `polipo` and if you are seaching for anonimity on the web you can try `tor`. Tor used to have `torbutton` plugin for firefox but seems they give their own browser. What I recommend is search for an addon to switch proxies in firefox. So what you can do is install `tor`.

`sudo apt-get install tor`

and configure polipo to work with tor:

```
cd /etc/polipo/
sudo wget https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbrowser.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/build-scripts/config/polipo.conf -O config
```

If you use `chrome/chromium` you can setup torbutton like setup through [this](http://lifehacker.com/5614732/create-a-tor-button-in-chrome-for-on+demand-anonymous-browsing)

If you just want one-time proxy just install `polipo` or `privoxy` [BUT NOT BOTH]

Go to firefox > preference  > advanced > network and setup manual proxy with

```
ip: localhost
port: 8118
```

Comment: Sounds promising, But when I try to set the proxy it says proxy refuses all connections.  The `wget` option also gives a 404 :(

Comment: what do you get on http://check.torproject.org/  when accessed from tor?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an application for that - you need a proxy in India. Then you need to enter the address of the proxy in your browser's settings. For Firefox it is Edit - Preferences - Advanced -  Network - Settings.

But, normally, most sites allow user to change the auto-detected country/currency anyway... have a better look